# What does % mean in an OCaml external declaration?

Tags: external, ocaml, ffi

Many `external` declarations in the OCaml standard library have a % at the beginning of the function name, such as the definition of `int_of_float`:

```
external int_of_float : float -> int = "%intoffloat"
```

What does the '%' mean?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There's a lot of `%foo` special primitives hiding in the compiler.  I think the best list is available in `bytecomp/translcore.ml`, in the ocaml compiler sources.  Let's see how many I can list here:

- Comparisons: %equal, %notequal, %lessthan, %greaterthan, %lessequal, %greaterequal, %compare

These comparisons have specialized versions for int, float, string, nativeint, int32 and int64, and will auto-specialize if the types are known at compile-time.

- Other primitives: `%identity, %ignore, %field0, %field1, %setfield0, %makeblock, %makemutable, %raise, %incr, %decr, %seqand, %seqor, %boolnot`
- Int ops:  `%negint, %succint, %predint, %addint, %subint, %mulint, %divint, %modint, %andint, %orint, %xorint, %lslint, %lsrint, %asrint`
- Int comparators (??): `%eq, %noteq, %ltint, %leint, %gtint, %geint`
- Float ops: `%intoffloat, %floatofint, %negfloat, %absfloat, %addfloat, %subfloat, %mulfloat, %divfloat`
- Float comparators: `%eqfloat, %noteqfloat, %ltfloat, %lefloat, %gtfloat, %gefloat`
- String ops: `%string_length, %string_safe_get, %string_safe_set, %string_unsafe_get, %string_unsafe_set`
- Array ops: `%array_length, %array_safe_get, %array_safe_set, %array_unsafe_get, %array_unsafe_set`
- Object manipulation: `%obj_size, %obj_field, %obj_set_field, %obj_is_int`
- Lazy: `%lazy_force`
- Nativeint,int32,int64 ops: `%{nativeint,int32,int64}: _of_int, _to_int, _neg, _add, _sub, _mul, _div, _mod, _and, _or, _xor, _lsl, _lsr, _asr`
- Int conversions: `%nativeint_{of,to}_int32, int64_{of,to}_int32, int64_{of,to}_nativeint`
- Bigarray operations: `%caml_ba_ref_{1,2,3}, %caml_ba_set_{1,2,3}, %caml_ba_unsafe_ref_{1,2,3}, %caml_ba_unsafe_set_{1,2,3}`
- Object Oriented: `%send, %sendself, %sendcache`

That's all I can find.

Comment: I'm not sure it really answers the question what "%" means in external declarations. Look at the answer by @Remi

Answer (score 12):

external with % are special external, that will be handled specially by the compiler. 
For example, with int_of_float, ocamlc will compile it into a call of some C function, but with ocamlopt, it will compile it into some special assembler opcode that transform double to integer.

Comment: I was wondering if it might be something like that.  Do you know if this feature and the available magic names are documented anywhere?